# CNN training with GPU exiting at epoch 1 with code 3221226505

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have installed TensorFlow, cudnn, and cuda and everything required to run TensorFlow with the GPU. When the code is ran, it exits the first epoch with the error code 3221226505. I am not sure why this is happening, running the program on google collab is working and only takes up around 1 GB of GPU memory.

python - 3.8.6,
cuda - 11.2.1,
cudnn - 11.2

```
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pandas as pd 
import time
import tensorflow as tf

gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  # Restrict TensorFlow to only allocate 1GB of memory on the first GPU
  try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(
        gpus[0],
        [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024)])
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Virtual devices must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
data = pd.read_csv("hmnist_28_28_RGB.csv") 

X = data.iloc[:, 0:-1]
y = data.iloc[:, -1]

X = X / 255.0
X = X.values.reshape(-1,28,28,3)

y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y.values,7)

print(y.shape)
print(X.shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(7))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=5, epochs=100, validation_split=0.3,verbose=1)
```

```
2021-02-17 16:16:20.046679: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-02-17 16:16:20.047795: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:20.073694: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:09:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.665GHz coreCount: 38 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-02-17 16:16:20.074002: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:20.090128: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:20.090262: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:20.094202: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:20.095533: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:20.100795: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:20.104097: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:20.104808: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:20.105102: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-02-17 16:16:20.105825: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-02-17 16:16:20.107415: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:09:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.665GHz coreCount: 38 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-02-17 16:16:20.107754: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:20.107967: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:20.108188: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:20.108410: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:20.108609: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:20.108798: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:20.108900: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:20.109119: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:20.109366: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-02-17 16:16:20.583958: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-02-17 16:16:20.584082: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2021-02-17 16:16:20.584220: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N 
2021-02-17 16:16:20.584499: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1024 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:09:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2021-02-17 16:16:20.585568: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
1 Physical GPUs, 1 Logical GPUs
(10015, 7)
(10015, 28, 28, 3)
2021-02-17 16:16:23.006535: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
Epoch 1/100
2021-02-17 16:16:23.409332: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:24.173684: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-02-17 16:16:24.177694: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll

[Done] exited with code=3221226505 in 7.113 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same issue for days and finally managed to solve it, it seems to be a `.dll` problem.

First I ran the program in Windows Power Shell, like this (in my case):

```
python -u "D:\Documents\Python\test.py"
```

And I noticed that, after the last three `"Successfully opened dynamic library..."` lines, there was a new error saying that it failed to load a library (specifically the `cudnn_adv_train64_8.dll`) with `Error 126`.

Then I just copied all the files in the cudnn `bin` folder:

```
cudnn_adv_infer64_8.dll
cudnn_adv_train64_8.dll
cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll
cudnn_cnn_train64_8.dll
cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll
cudnn_ops_train64_8.dll
cudnn64_8.dll
```

And pasted them into the CUDA `bin` folder (in my case):

`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\bin`

Now it seems to work fine and it definitely uses my GPU, because training time dropped from 2-3 minutes to 20 seconds.

Hope it works for you as well.